# How to create PDF file from Uint8Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, amazon-s3

I uploaded some PDF files in Amazon s3 and I want to prepare these files for users.

First I get the content of a file using aws-sdk:

```
s3.getObject(
    { Bucket: "books", Key: "book.pdf" },
    function (error, data) {
        if (error != null) {
            alert("Failed to retrieve an object: " + error);
        } else {
            text = data.Body;
        }
    }
);
```

So the text would be the content of that PDF file. A Uint8Array.

I use it this way:

```
    <button onclick="() => download('file.pdf', text)">download</button>
```

And a PDF file will be downloaded. When I open that file it says "PDF document is damaged".

What is the problem?

Comment: You haven't shown us all the code but your getObject call does not look right. You should not be assigning to a variable outside the callback. I suspect you are not doing async properly.

Comment: Are you sure that `text` is in PDF format?